# How to Search Max Date for specific record from Multi Tables VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Written code is under  and i am getting empty record

```
SELECT  dbo.InvoiceDetails.CID, dbo.ProductDetails.InvoiceID, dbo.InvoiceDetails.Inv_ID, dbo.Product.PID, dbo.ProductDetails.ProductID, dbo.ProductDetails.SellingPrice, dbo.InvoiceDetails.InvoiceDate
FROM dbo.Customer 
INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceDetails ON dbo.Customer.ID = dbo.InvoiceDetails.CID
INNER JOIN dbo.ProductDetails ON dbo.InvoiceDetails.Inv_ID = dbo.ProductDetails.InvoiceID
INNER JOIN  dbo.Product ON dbo.ProductDetails.ProductID = dbo.Product.PID
WHERE  InvoiceDate=(SELECT MAX(Invoicedate) FROM InvoiceDetails WHERE Customer.CID = 2 and ProductID=4);
```

(I am Getting Empty Record, no errors)
Any suggestions welcome

Comment: I would start by looking to see what this subquery returns:                                                  
        (SELECT MAX(Invoicedate) FROM InvoiceDetails where Customer.CID = 2 and ProductID=4);

Comment: Thanks Ryan Wilson :  i add this theory just for to find out the max date..... before i add instead of this  (where productid=4 and customer.id=2) but it give me all records .... i need only with max date

Comment: Joel Coehoom:   Same Result, Empty Records, it cannot identify the records

Comment: I would rework your query and do a select top 1 with an order by InvoiceDate Descending, see my answer below.

Comment: Ryan Wilson Thank You.... It Works with Top 1, Outstanding Thinking

Comment: Im glad that works, if you are happy with that, please mark my below answer as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT TOP 1  dbo.InvoiceDetails.CID, dbo.ProductDetails.InvoiceID, 
    dbo.InvoiceDetails.Inv_ID, dbo.Product.PID, 
    dbo.ProductDetails.ProductID, 
    dbo.ProductDetails.SellingPrice, dbo.InvoiceDetails.InvoiceDate
    FROM dbo.Customer 
    INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceDetails ON dbo.Customer.ID = 
    dbo.InvoiceDetails.CID
    INNER JOIN dbo.ProductDetails ON dbo.InvoiceDetails.Inv_ID = 
    dbo.ProductDetails.InvoiceID
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Product ON dbo.ProductDetails.ProductID = 
    dbo.Product.PID
    WHERE Customer.CID = 2 and ProductID = 4
    ORDER BY InvoiceDate DESC
```

Comment: Its Work Correctly, Thank you Ryan Wilson